# Strange Camera Shutter sound from Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, audio, google-chrome, malware

My Macbook Pro (Mid-2010, Running OS 10.9) has been making a strange camera shutter sound every couple minutes for the last two weeks. I initially thought it was an ad from one of my Chrome tabs, but it has happened when I've had different pages opened and haven't been able to pinpoint an ad that could be doing this. From what I've noticed so far, it only happens when I have Google Chrome open. Does anyone know what this could be and how I could stop it?

Also, is there an audio log file that I can access on my computer that would allow me to find out what program is creating this sound?

Comment: The sound is not the same as the screen grab (CMD+Shift+3) sound.

Answer (score 1):

*purely speculation*, but is it the screen grab sound (try hitting CMD+shift+3)?

then it *could* be malware that takes automated screenshots.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this issue by uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome.